# Mongodb timeout error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I've a nodejs application. When it start it connects to a mongodb listening at 127.0.0.1:27017 (using mongoose). The application uses 5 separate collections connected with one key from primary collection such as (user._id where 'User' is the primary collection). When application start I want to populate database with let's say 100K records. So I wrote a for loop for 100K iterations as shown below,

```
  for (var ii=0; ii < count; ii++) {
    async.series([
      function(callback) {
        //Build User record
        var user = new User();
        user.email = ii.toString() + '@example.com';
        user.save(function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err, null);
          }
          user_id = data._id;
          console.log('New User:' + user_id);
          u_count++;
          callback();
        });
      },  
      function(callback) {
         //Save collection 2 information about newly saved user (user_id);
         var photo = new Photo();
         photo._user = user_id;
         photo.save() {
           ......
           callback();
         }
      },
      function(callback) {
         //collection 3 ...
         ....
      }
      //3 more collection save calls in series
    ), function(err) { //Final callback for each iteration
         ...
      });
    }); //end of async.series()
  } //end of for loop
```

If the count=10000, the database populates correctly but if I increase that number to 100K, I start to get following errors,

```
{ [MongoError: connection 4 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 4 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out' }
   Saving Photo: Internal error while saving employee record 
  Error while running async.seriesMongoError: connection 4 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out
```

'4' I believe is the number of connection with mongodb. This varies, depending when (or which async operation is executing) you get this error.

Im not able to track this error. Any help is appreciated.

--Atarangp

Comment: don't use async series for this task. use bulk writes https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/bulk-write-operations . create seperate bulk write for different collection

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But bulk write works with one collection at a time. I do I make it work across many collections maintaining those relations?